# Using an if statement with a percentage in Jquery always returns false

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've got a small amount of code that creates an endless carousel. When it's done in pixels, it works fine:

```
$('.left').click(function(){
        $('.box').animate({left: '+=100'}, 100, function(){
        var $last = $('.box').last();
        if ($last.css('left') == '100px') {
            $last.prependTo('.container').before('\n\r');
            $('.box').css('left','0px');
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/4CuLE/1/

But if I change from pixels to percentages, it does **not** work and the `if statement` is **false**.

```
$('.left').click(function(){
        $('.box').animate({left: '+=5%'}, 200, function(){
        var $last = $('.box').last();
        if ($last.css('left') == '5%') {
            $last.prependTo('.container').before('\n\r').hide().fadeIn();
            $('.box').css('left','0%');
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/4CuLE/2/

Would anyone know why this is? I'm working with a responsive layout, so I need to keep the percentages.

Comment: Try to `console.log($last.css('left'))`.  Chances are it's a pixel value not a percentage.  jQuery is probably calculating the exact value and setting that.

Comment: When getting styles in javascript, it's generally pixel values that are returned, sometimes even if you set it in percentages, so a good rule of thumb is that if you have to use percentages, do the calculations yourself based on parent element etc.

Answer (score 5):

According to [jQuery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/), `.css()` return the *computed* value.

> Note that the computed style of an element may not be the same as the value specified for that element in a style sheet. For example, computed styles of dimensions are almost always pixels, but they can be specified as em, ex, px or % in a style sheet. Different browsers may return CSS color values that are logically but not textually equal, e.g., #FFF, #ffffff, and rgb(255,255,255).

So you may not compare it with percent value.

Comment: That seems odd. I was just going by the inline style, because that says `left: 17%`. Would there be a way to compare to that inline style?

Comment: Maybe using `.style.cssText` ?

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that, even if you originally set it with a percentage, jQuery's `animate()` method automatically converts it to pixels. Therefore, when you then call `css()`, you get a pixel value.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @Nathan P. you may not compare percent values, but if you need to keep your CSS percentages, you can retrive the box width in pixels with `$('.box').width()` like this:

```
var boxWidth = $('.box').width()
$('.left').click(function(){
    $('.box').animate({left: '+='+boxWidth}, 100, function(){
        var $last = $('.box').last();
        if ($last.css('left') == boxWidth+'px') {
            $last.prependTo('.container').before('\n\r');
            $('.box').css('left','0px');
        }
    });
});
```

[here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4CuLE/3/)

Note all css dimensions are in percentage.

Hope it helps